# Iphone Hide uitabbar on first tab

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

There are 5 tabs in my app , first tab is a welcome tab, when user clicks the first tab it show the welcome screen, but only on first tab i want to hide the tabbar
I want to hide the tabbar on the first tab because its a welcome view. I did searching but could not hide it , i did this in my welcome controller view didload.

```
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
```

it hides but leaving the space empty.

Working on xcode 4.3.2 , storyboard, ios 5

Comment: For that you need to implement the first view shows the UITable view and then after you shows the UITabbar.

Comment: @neonsamuel there are 5 tabs in my app , first tab is a welcome tab, when user clicks the first tab it show the welcome screen, but only on first tab i want to hide the tabbar

Comment: Hey @RaheelSadiq have you any solution , please tell me

Comment: @RaviJSS I have accepted an answer, you can check solution there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You Hide tabBar then how can you navigate to tab 2nd and 3rd.
I suggest to add welcomeView and after welcomeView add tabBar.

Or you can use this code

```
[self hideTabBar:self.tabBarController];


- (void) hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        } 
        else 
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
        }

    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];    
}

[self  showTabBar:self.tabBarController];  

- (void) showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller {

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", view);

            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 431, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];

            } 
            else 
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 431)];
            }


        }

        [UIView commitAnimations]; 
    }
```

Comment: i did this, as -> on welcome screen table row to tabbar controller, it does not segue

Comment: You are right on how to navigate on 2nd and 3rd tabbar. what is the solution, because it does not segue from welcome screen to tabbarView

Comment: first tell me that what is in your welcome screen....is there any button , so you can navigate to tabBar after click on them..

Comment: there is table view, from where i want to start the tabbar

Comment: now i do what , first tab is welcome tab, and on table view did select row i change the tab to 2nd tab, and it shows the 2nd tab, now i want to show the tabbar

Comment: ok....so now in viewWillApppear of welcomeView just use upper code of hide tabBar, and on didselectrow just use [self  showTabBar:self.tabBarController]; ....

Answer (score 0):

> What is the bar button name.

Give like this,

```
barbtnName.hidden=YES;
```

It will Work.

Answer (score 0):

On ios 7 / 8 (xcode 6) to hide the tabbar from one view but not from the others you just need to add the following "User Defined Runtime Attributes" on the affected views (all of them):

Key Path = tabBarController.tabBar.hidden

Type = boolean

Value = true / false (depending on checkbox)

LF

Comment: Can you explain it ?